# Как определить число "строк", "колонок" в 2d массиве

Tags: java, массивы

То есть в метод передается допустим int[4][5] i
Хотелось бы элегантно, без циклов определить число "строк", "колонок" в двумерном массиве. Со строками понятно i.length отдаст 4, а вот колонки как?

Comment: Все-таки есть смысл проверить на null и также на размер - а вдруг там и нулевого элемента тоже нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если гарантируется, что все "строки" одинаковой длины и в массиве есть хотя бы одна "строка":

```
int rows = a.length;
int columns = a[0].length;
```

Без соблюдения этих условий -- никак.

Answer (score 1):

Если в каждом столбце заданного двумерного массива равное количество элементов, то можно просто воспользоваться:

```
i[0].length;
```

Но если есть вероятность, что в разных столбцах может быть разное количество элементов, то для определения максимального количества строк можно пробежаться по каждом столбцу по отдельности:

```
int maxRow = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
    if (maxRow < i[j].length) {
        maxRow = i[j].length;
    }
}
```

Comment: В строках могут быть не только массивы разной длины но и `null`

Answer (score 0):

Что мешает вам взять `i[0].length`?